is it possible to pass the event of addEventListener to another addEventListener?
I run this from a chrome extension using a content script, and I got no error, the copy event seems to be successfully passed to the paste event, but copyEvent.clipboardData.setData have no effect inside the paste event, it works fine outside the paste event.
document.addEventListener("copy", fixClipboard_handler_for_copy);

async function fixClipboard_handler_for_copy(myCopyEvent) {
  // this works fine
  // myCopyEvent.preventDefault();
  // myCopyEvent.clipboardData.setData('text/html', "fffffffffmyCopyEventf");
  // myCopyEvent.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', "ffffffzzzzzzffffmyCopyEvent");
  try {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.addEventListener('paste', wrappedPasteHandler);
      document.execCommand('paste')
      document.removeEventListener('paste', wrappedPasteHandler);
    }, 0); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error in fixClipboard_handler_for_copy: ', err);
  }

  function wrappedPasteHandler(myPasteEvent) {
    document.removeEventListener('paste', wrappedPasteHandler);
    fixClipboard_handler_for_paste(myPasteEvent, myCopyEvent);
  }
  
  async function fixClipboard_handler_for_paste(pasteEvent, copyEvent) {
    try {
      copyEvent.clipboardData.setData('text/html', "ffffffffff");
      copyEvent.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', "ffffffzzzzzzffff");
        console.log('Modified HTML text has been written to the clipboard.');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to write HTML to the clipboard: ', err);
    }

    pasteEvent.preventDefault();
    copyEvent.preventDefault();
  }

}

fixClipboard_handler_for_paste also works fine when i change copyEvent.clipboardData.setData to navigator.clipboard.write
so the problem seems to be that we cannot pass an event to another event. am i wrong? is there an alternative way to pass an event to another event?
I already have "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite" in my MV3 permissions.

what does we cannot pass an event to another event  mean? you can pass an event to as many functions as you feel you want to

What is the end goal? There may be a different solution.

@Jaromanda X i mean to pass an event object from one event listener to another event listener, it seems that events in JavaScript are not simple data objects that can be passed around like that; so i want to confirm this theory.

@wOxxOm the end goal is to simply learn and understand if it is possible to pass an event object to another event. because i was working on a solution to fix the clipboard content to make it compatible with onenote who does not accept some css properties like background-color on div tags when i copy something from chrome. i solved it using navigator.clipboard.write, but i got the idea of using the copy event inside the paste event object instead of clipboard.write inside the paste event but it did not work as you see, so i just wanted to learn why it does not work like that.

Patching clipboardData may require doing it in the MAIN world. And indeed copy/paste events are dispatched by the browser and aren't just simple objects, but some changes (e.g. clipboardData) may be explicitly remembered if the specification says so.

@wOxxOm i just tested it now: MAIN world is worst, even my working code using navigator.clipboard.write stops working, and document.execCommand('paste') stops working too. Only synthetic pasting works: this document.dispatchEvent(new Event('paste', {bubbles: true,cancelable: true}))  works if i manually add the clipboardData property
myEvent.clipboardData = { getData: function(format)....}  then navigator.clipboard.write starts working. so MAIN world seems to be more restricted
